# What does this double @ syntax mean in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, payara

I'm pretty new to Docker and I'm trying to containerize our web application. Currently we're using Payara Community as our application server.

The Payara basic Dockerfile is located here:

https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/master/appserver/extras/docker-images/basic/src/main/docker/Dockerfile

The first line looks like this:

```
FROM @docker.java.image@
```

I don't fully understand the @@ syntax. I suppose it's a way to insert variables into the Dockerfile but I can't find how to specify them in my own Dockerfile. Would it be possible this way to set a specific JDK of my own choice?

Comment: It's an external tool they use to modify the Dockerfile. It's not Docker syntax. As far as I can see, it's a part of Maven called POM. The variable is defined here: https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/b042bd89732c41610962c8da63d974cecd5d5c21/appserver/extras/docker-images/pom.xml#L143

Comment: @HansKilian Thanks, I guess that answers it. Well spotted. Unfortunately they only support JDK8 and 11, but our application is in 17.